# PHP Upload file-type and -size restrictions

Tags: php, mysql, upload

ok, so I made this and this works just fine and well:

```
$file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile1']['name'];
$file_name_for_db = ($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile1']['name']);
$new_file_name = $id."_pic1_".$file_name;
$path = "../users/".$username_session."/photos/".$new_file_name;

if($ufile !=none)
{
    copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile1']['tmp_name'], $path);
    $path_of_pic = "../users/".$username_session."/photos/".$id."_pic1_".$file_name_for_db;
    mysql_query("UPDATE pictures SET pic_1 = '".$path_of_pic."' WHERE id = '$id'");
    header("location:../upload/");
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Now what I've been trying to do is add restrictions.

I've looked through many restriction tutorials, they don't work, always returns error no matter what.

I just want to restric from users uploading anything other than pictures (.png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .bmp) and no more than 5mb

I can do this in HTML, but you can easily get past that. I'm pretty new to programming, so I apologize if the way I write my codes is poor and bulky.

This site has helped me a whole bunch a few times! You guys are awesome! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this link will help you to restrict images other then `.jpg, .jpeg, and so on` also the maximum upload size, and if you want to resize the image then also follow the tutorial : http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/upload-and-resize-image-with-php.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !@imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($path))) {
    // (most likely) not an image
}
```

And:

```
if( filesize($path) > 5<<20) {
    // image is bigger than 5MB
}
```

Comment: if( !@imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($path))) { 
    // (most likely) not an image 
echo error not an image;
} 
else
{
upload image
}

is this the way that would work or vise versa?